# How can one define the commutator between 2 rectangular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

How can one define the commutator between 2 rectangular matrices ?

Given $J$ and $T$, can we define what it means to say

$[J,T] = JT-TJ$

when $T$ and $J$ are rectangular, and may only share 1 dimension

i.e

$J$ is $N\times M$; $T$ is $N\times M$

and / or

$J$ is $N\times M$; $T$ is $N\times K$

Comment: Hi, you should use MathJax for equations. As for your question, you don't define the commutator if the matrices are not square matrices.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @joseph h You can define the commutator (like in the Lie Algebra), but not in a way the OP suggested. His definition explicitly requires that we have defined multiplication. But we do not have (standard) definition of matrix multiplication for both $T J$ and $J T$ when $T$ and $J$ are not square matrices.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\Natl}{\mathbf{N}}$An $m \times n$ real matrix $A = [A_{j}^{i}]$ may be viewed as a real-valued function on the set $\Natl \times \Natl$ of ordered pairs of natural numbers that is zero unless $0 \leq i < m$ and $0 \leq j < n$. That is, we can "pad $A$ with $0$s," obtaining an infinite array with only finitely many non-zero entries.

Two such "finitely supported" arrays may be added or multiplied using the conventional sum and product:
$$
A + B = [A_{j}^{i} + B_{j}^{i}],\qquad
AB = \biggl[\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} A_{k}^{i} B_{j}^{k}\biggr].
$$
(The infinite sum in the formula for $AB$ has only finitely many non-zero terms for each $(i, j)$ so there is no issue of convergence.) These definitions commute with inclusion of ordinary finite matrices provided the "classical" sum or product are defined. As a result, we can add or multiply matrices of arbitrary finite sizes, and can therefore define the commutator for matrices of arbitrary finite sizes in a way that naturally generalizes the ordinary commutator for square matrices of the same size.

Answer (score 0):

You can define it, but it's not very useful.

Matrix multiplication $J\cdot  T$ is possible only when the number of columns of the first matrix $J$ is identical to the number of rows of the second $T$. This also applies to the reverse order product $T\cdot  J$ if you want to calculate their commutator.

So if you have $J_{m\times n}$ and $T_{n\times m}\ , \ n\ne m$ you can define $[J,T] = (JT)_{m\times m}-(TJ)_{n\times n}$ which is not very useful. Note they will never commute such that $J\cdot  T=T\cdot J$ or $[J,T]=0$

For matrices to actually satisfy $[J,T]=0$, they need to be *square* or $m=n$, since the requirement for commuting matrices/operators is that they be simultaneously diagonizable and therefore have an inverse (and the inverse of a non-square matrix is not defined).